ADX, RSI, Moving Averages Indicator with Pinescript v5 or v6
I want to make a program which plots labels above candles with either 'A', 'B', or 'C'. 'A' shows that you can have an entry , 'B' shows that you can add, and 'C' shows to add all the remaining amount. These need to be on a basis of ADX, RSI and moving averages. Please help me with the code because I have no clue on how to program it or the logic behind it.
Thanks
I know how to plot the labels above, just the problem is that I can't understand how to use ADX, RSI or Moving averages. I need someone to make me understand how I can use the A, B, or C with the above, or just give the code so I can make myself understand.
